# Is there an function translating the ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE to the format used when calling drop

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm having troubles in getting the ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE of the information schema PROCEDURES table in the correct format to be used in a drop statement.

Full example below:

Having a procedure created like

```
create or replace procedure proc1(P1 FLOAT, P2 FLOAT) returns string
    language javascript as $$ $$;
```

Selecting from the INFORMATION SCHEMA/PROCEDURES:

```
SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE FROM TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES
  WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'PROC1' ;
```

Produces the following result

```
PROCEDURE_NAME ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE   
-------------- -------------------- 
PROC1          (P1 FLOAT, P2 FLOAT)
```

A drop command for dropping the PROC1 procedure must look like:

```
drop procedure PROC1 (FLOAT, FLOAT)
```

So the question here is how do I go from "(P1 FLOAT, P2 FLOAT)" to  "(FLOAT, FLOAT)"?
I.e is there a function that allows me to run something like:

```
SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, SOMEFUNC(ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE) AS ARGTYPELIST
  FROM TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'PROC1' ;
```

where the Column ARGTYPELIST would be in the format (FLOAT, FLOAT).

I have tried using regexp_replace but can not seem to get this correct.
Perhaps there are better ways?
I need this to be a pure SQL solution. The characters "(" ")" is not required to remain. Some expected output

```
"(P1 FLOAT, P2 FLOAT)"  --> "FLOAT,FLOAT"
"()"                    -->  ""
"(P1 FLOAT)"            --> "FLOAT"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex option. It's a little messy, but will handle extra whitespace as well.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('(P1 FLOAT, P2 STRING)', '([(,]\\s*)\\w*\\s*(\\w*\\)?)', '\\1\\2');
```

Returns

```
(FLOAT, STRING)
```

This version will remove the Parens:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('(P1 FLOAT, P2 STRING)', '\\(?([,]\\s*)?\\w*\\s*(\\w*)\\)?', '\\1\\2');
```

Answer (score 0):

David's answer is cleaner than this but since I'm not great with regex here is another option:

```sql
SELECT 
    procedure_catalog,
    procedure_schema,
    procedure_name,
    argument_signature,
    '(' || array_to_string(array_agg(split_part(trim(value), ' ', 2)), ',') || ')'
from 
    database_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES,
    lateral flatten (INPUT => SPLIT(trim(translate(ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE,'"()','')), ','))
WHERE 
    PROCEDURE_NAME = 'PROC1'
group by procedure_catalog, procedure_schema, procedure_name, argument_signature
;
```

Comment: Anybody finding ways to parse data without regex is a friend of mine.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

this is something of a quick hack since I've hardcoded extracting each element, but it works fine with SP w/ no parameters up to 5 parameters (which you can easily extend w/ copy/paste.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION sp_param(PARMLIST VARCHAR)
    RETURNS VARCHAR
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS 
    $$
     '(' ||
     REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SLICE(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(PARMLIST, ' '),1,2),''),'\\)','') || 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SLICE(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(PARMLIST, ' '),3,4),''),'\\)','') || 
     REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SLICE(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(PARMLIST, ' '),5,6),''),'\\)','') ||
     REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SLICE(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(PARMLIST, ' '),7,8),''),'\\)','') ||
     REGEXP_REPLACE(ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_SLICE(STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(PARMLIST, ' '),9,10),''),'\\)','') ||
     ')'
    $$;
```

try it out:

```
SELECT PROCEDURE_NAME, ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE, sp_param(ARGUMENT_SIGNATURE) AS ARGTYPELIST
  FROM TEST_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES WHERE PROCEDURE_NAME = 'PROC1' ;
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I'll go for David's solution as this will allow me to run without having to create a function.